# PHP XML: how to foreach over two XML tags

Tags: php, xml

Currently I have this

```
foreach($file->garden as $item)
```

which works fine for `<garden>`, but I'd like to include in the `foreach` so that it loops over `<kitchen>` as well.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Try it. Show us the code, if you don't succeed, and we will help you.

Comment: Can you show some of your code? What does your XML look like? Do you use SimpleXML or what do you use?

Comment: Everything works for me, but I was wondering if its possible to do it like this foreach($file->garden && $file->kitchen as $item) I know how to do it by making 2 different foreach loops but I want to simplify my code so if its possible to make them one liner its better

Comment: No, you have to do two seperate `foreach` loops, nested or after each other. See: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks man, that answers my question :)

Comment: What is this? SimpleXML? If you use XML parser that support XPath, you can use XPath to select multiple elements at once : `*[self::garden or self::kitchen]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<?php
foreach($file->children() as $item) {
  echo $item . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Will output:
Garden
Kitchen

Comment: This outputs all tags though which is not what I want